# Attribute is missing the android namespace prefixx

Tags: android

hello guys i tried my best on this one but :'( what am i doing wrong??? i dont get it

```
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="59dp"
    android:string="comment"
    android:system.out.println(name);
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu"
    android:textSize="19sp"
    tools:ignore="NewApi,SpUsage" />
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: "Attribute is missing the android namespace prefix" when im trying to run it on eclipse.

Comment: Can you paste the traceback?

Comment: im not sure what does traceback mean. sorry im a starter :'(

Comment: The error traceback, but well try deleting this line:

    android:system.out.println(name);
and change this:

    android:string="comment"
for this:

    android:text="comment"

Comment: i did what you told me and now it comes out a new error. it says [l18n]hardcoded string "comment", should use @string resource

Comment: It's not an error, You can use both hardcoded strings or strings resource, but your app should compile

Comment: okay got it :)
also when i right click on the xml file and run as - android application, a windows pops up saying that my project contains errors please fic them before running the application. ( the only error i had was the one we already solved. am i doing some wrong?

Comment: On your project, is there any red cross on top of it? If there is, you have to click that file and see what Eclipse tells you

Answer (score 0):

Right below the defined line `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` at the top of your file, typically the first line, you should add the following one:

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

This will fix the *Attribute is missing the android namespace prefix* error.

By the way, `android:system.out.println(name);` makes no sense to me in a xml file. Just delete that line.

Comment: I deleted that and also i have <relativelayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" then bellow that i have what u told me to write. From what i see eclipse doesnt have a problem with that i guess.

Comment: Well, it should work then! As a matter of fact, it is `<RelativeLayout ...` and not `<relativelayout ...` :)

Comment: thats btw after im done creating the app how do i make it a apk file so i can move it to my phone?

Comment: Just run the project. Connect your phone via USB and you run it directly on the device. (You can find lots of questions answering to that in detail, if you find any issues with that). If my answer really helped you, please accept the answer :)